# Open Links in Default Browser using Phonegap/Cordova

Tags: cordova

I'm developing an app which acts as a wrapper to display an external mobile-friendly website (i.e. live from the internet) within an app using Phonegap/Cordova v3.4.

Everything works and loads fine.

My problem is that I want any "external links" on that page to open in the OS' default browser, rather than within the app itself (i.e. links to Facebook).

I know the standard procedure for this for local HTML files by using the `InAppBrowser` code:

```
window.open(url, '_system');
```

Since the page is **not** on a local HTML file, the `_system` target is not having any effect.

I have copied the `phonegap.js`, `cordova.js` and `cordova_plugins.js` file to the external site and load them when it detects that is being called within an app, however it still does not allow the links to open in the OS browser.

Currently testing on HTC One Max on Android 4.3, iOS Emulator and WP8 Emulator.

Full code available from GitHub for the app - and Pastebin for the javascript included on the external site it loads.

- https://github.com/devonto/devonto/blob/master/www/index.html
- http://pastebin.com/rQXV1u8J

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi chris, did you solve this. Im having similar issue in my app.

Comment: No, never did solve it... been side-tracked with other projects, but picking it back up again... since then, there have been updates to PhoneGap - may take a look at it again. I will update this thread, if I get anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

I found that I had to be sure I was passing "http://" as part of my link when opening with the '_system' context. Trying to open "google.com" did nothing, trying to open "http://google.com" worked.

Comment: Sorry, this isn't the solution in this case - all URLs were being passed the full HTTP prefix.

Answer (score 0):

The window.open method is provided by the Inappbrowser provided by Phonegap.If you want to open any HTML page in the OS' default browser,you can use the window.location object of the browser in this way.

```
window.location.href="https://www.google.com/".
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: Thanks, however that performs the same action. It is changing the href of the inAppBrowser's window - rather than opening a new system browser window. Any other advice?

Answer (score 0):

My workaround involves two parts: changing the callback for "loadstart" emitted by InAppBrowser when a new page loads, then having some logic in your webview's JavaScript to close the window if it's an external link.

CORDOVA EXAMPLE:

```
var host = "mobile.myapp.com";
...
function pageLoad(e){
  // if the event's url doesn't contain your domain, it's an external link
  if (e.url.indexOf(host) === -1 {
    external = window.open(e.url, '_system');
    external.addEventListener('loadstart', pageLoad);
  }
}
app.addEventListener('loadstart', pageLoad)
```

WEBVIEW HTML:

```
<a onclick="externalLinkHandler(link)">
```

WEBVIEW JAVASCRIPT:

```
var externalLinkHandler = function(link) {
  var newWindow = window.open(link, '_blank');
  // If the window links to another page on your domain, it's not an external link
  // so you can immediately close the new window you opened in your webview. The new
  // external link will remain open in the system browser window opened when Cordova
  // detected you were changing pages to an external link.
  if (window.location.host === 'mobile.myapp.com') {
    newWindow.close();
  }
}
```

The user shouldn't see the quick page open-close because the external link will have opened in the system browser. When they close the system browser, they'll just see the last page -- the new window you're opening here won't stay open.

NOTE: I use this in places where there's a possibility the link is an external link. If you're hard-coding it to be an internal page redirection, just use hrefs. You don't want to open a new window for every internal link you handle. This will just immediately close the new window that's opened if it's an external link.

Comment: Thanks - not quite sure if this can be applied to my project - but perhaps my project can be refactored to work better... my Cordova code is on GitHub: http://tinyurl.com/ng6nwcc and the script I include on the external site is at http://pastebin.com/rQXV1u8J